# Data caching client side in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, localdatacache

Is it possible to do data caching in client-side in asp.net using c#?

I am planning to cache a `Dataset`. If so can you please provide a sample?

Comment: What kind of application are you making? I witch language are you programming?

Comment: working in asp.net & c#.net web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real option you have to store large amounts of data client side is by using the `ViewState`.  It will only exist on the page you add it to though.  So if you are jumping around from page to page it won't really work.  In that case you really should be using `Session` or `Application Cache` depending on your scenario.

So if you are doing something where you are always on the same page and just doing many `PostBacks` for things like paging or sorting then `ViewState` will work fine but do realize you will be passing large amounts of data back and forth to the server each time a `PostBack` is made.

Eg:

```
// Set it
ViewState["YourData"] = yourDataSet;

// Get it
DataSet ds = ViewState["YourData"] as DataSet;
```

`Session` and the `Application Cache` are accessed the same way.  Just replace `ViewState` with the word `Session` or `Cache`.

More information regarding the 3 methods can be found on MSDN:

1. [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)
2. [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
3. [Application Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)

You might want to check out the following links as well:

[Advantages of Cache vs Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428634/cache-v-s-session)

[Session State v ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899591/session-state-v-viewstate)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PTCacheSessionViewState.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net & c#.net web application its best to cache these kind of things in server side datacache.

The only form of client side cache that I can think of for this is to put the dataset in a session object

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use from external library **LocalCaching.dll** for **.Net Application client side caching**

this [codeproject article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/9420/client-side-caching-for-net-applications#CreatingaCacheManager3) is a best solution for this library